# What flowering plants could I keep outdoors in pots in winter in Holland?

Tags: flowers, plant-recommendations, container-gardening, winter-gardening

I want to put flowers or plants in a flower pot in front of the house. I live in Holland and it is raining a lot there and there are not a lot of sunny days, and winters are not very cold (0 °C is minimal). I want some plant/flowers which can survive winter outside.

The place where I want to put flowers/plant has sun only in the morning.

Any suggestions would be good.

Comment: Aleksandra, Having sun just in the morning is barely enough to support vegetative beauty.  You are asking about potted plants for out of doors that flower?  How cold do your winters get?  Flowers and winter aren't meant to go together.  Main thing is that the daylight hours are so short.  Few plants can provide profuse flowers in the shade.  Some of the absolute best are impatiens and begonias.  Mix with ornamental grasses such as mexican feather grass or orange sedge.  Ipomea is incredible for spilling over the edge of your pot.

Comment: How warm does your summer get? Stormy, I think Aleksandra just wants the plants to survive the winter (not necessarily bloom or stay in bloom in winter). Tell me if I'm wrong, Aleksandra.

Answer (score 3):

In the Netherlands bulbs are very popular. If you choose different plant bulbs, and put them together in a pot, the one will bloom after the other. The earliest bloomers are for instance *Galanthus nivalis* (Sneeuwklokje), and the *Crocus* can be very early as well. As early as January/February, it depends on the winter (it can freeze as well, 0 °C as a minimum is not what I experience).

After *Crocus*, Daffodils (*Narcissus*), and Tulips will bloom, and so on. I am not sure how well your Dutch is, but here is a [bulb calendar](https://zaaikalender.com/bloembollen-planten/).

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to go to your local garden center in the early winter and again in late winter and purchase plants that are blooming then.  Personally, I'd suggest a mixture of plants with attractive foliage, and plants that flower.  That way the plants with nice foliage can stay all year, and you can swap out other plants at different seasons.  Another way to do it would be to plant flowers that create a stunning display all winter, and replace them with spring flowers, then summer flowers.